# Using cc-by-sa 4.0 in a server

Tags: cc-by-sa

Can one build a server that uses a cc by sa database for computation but does not respond with the       cc 4.0 without giving attribution or follwing the terms of cc 4.0?

Comment: The simplest answer is that if no CC-licensed material (in original or derivative form)  is ever transferred to another person's machine/possession, then the CC license places no obligations on you. However, it is not fully clear to me whether this simple answer describes your specific case or not.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: **no, since you are redistributing the material, you need to give attribution**.  Both to the original database as well as to the content if it is under a *by*-license.

Assuming you haven't modified the content under the license, then from the [Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 licence text](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) you need only to

> **give appropriate credit**, provide a link to the license,
>   and indicate if changes were made.
>   You may do so in *any reasonable manner*,
>   but not in any way that suggests the licensor endorses you or your
>   use.

You *cannot* redistribute without giving appropriate credit, but *any reasonable manner* can be interpreted quite leniently.

I would suggest that you both add the attribution in the API documentation, as well as strongly consider adding attribution notice in the actual API response, either in a `copyright` or `license` field.

Comment: I am not really distributing it as it will be used only for computational work.

Comment: Its like request -> processing -> result stored in server and  another irrelevant data sent to user

Comment: This processing will use the database

Comment: @compenthusiast, can you update your question with information on how you are using the database?